# How can i change the Gradle Version in InteliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, java-home

I have the Error: "Found invalid Gradle JVM configuration"
"JDK 17.0.1 isn´t compatible with gradle 7.1. Please fix JAVA_HOME enviroment variable"

Im not sure why it says gradle 7.1. The gradle Version i have is 7.4.2. This version should work with JDK 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in the `./gradle/wrapper` directory.

In the file, you can define the distribution URL from which Gradle is loaded. For example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip
```

As far as I know, IntelliJ adopts the version.

According to the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), Gradle 7.3 is the first Gradle version that supports JDK 17. You could try that one.